# Mysql statement works when run directly but doesn't in my php file

Tags: php, mysql

When i run this code in mysql workbench it works but in my php it only returns an empty array.

```
<?PHP
session_start();

$results = array();
if( $query =  $db->query("SELECT business_id, BusinessName, date, post ".
  "FROM WolfeboroC.posts ".
  "JOIN WolfeboroC.users ON users.recid = posts.business_id ".
  "WHERE City= '$city' AND State='$state'".
  "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 500") ) 
{
  while($record = $query->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $results[] = $record;
  }
  $query->close();
}

echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Comment: I strongly doubt this would work in your mysql console.

Comment: why you are concatenating the query?

Comment: Just output the query and you'll notice the errors in there

Comment: well it does work i took out the quotes though

Comment: hint: join goes before where clauses...

Comment: oh whoops forgot to take that out

Comment: @Mosty Mostacho mysqli_result Object ( ) is what i get if i try to print_r($query)

Comment: @Sebas when i changed the Where clause location and removed the concats it still didn't work

Comment: @user2354835, show the updated query please, in your question's body

Comment: its included in a file called connection.php

Comment: @user2354835 as per your new edit, `"ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 500") )` where's the missing ending semi-colon?

Comment: @Linger that gave a syntax error

Comment: @Fred-ii- its an if statement theres no ending semicolon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can't use the structure

```
FROM
WHERE
JOIN
```

You have to use

```
FROM
JOIN
WHERE
```

Secondly, you are missing a space at the end of `'$state'"`

```
"FROM WolfeboroC.posts ". "WHERE city= '$city' && state='$state'".
"JOIN WolfeboroC.users ON users.recid = posts.business_id ".
```

So I'm pretty sure that doesn't really work on MySQL, as you mentioned.

There are also some PHP errors. Use this code:

```
if($result = $db->query(
  "SELECT business_id, BusinessName, date, post ".
  "FROM WolfeboroC.posts ".
  "JOIN WolfeboroC.users ON users.recid = posts.business_id ".
  "WHERE City= '$city' AND State='$state' ".
  "ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 500")) {
  while($record = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $results[] = $record;
  }
  $result->close();
}
```

Comment: SELECT business_id, BusinessName, date, post
FROM posts JOIN users ON users.recid = posts.business_id 
WHERE City= 'houston' AND State='TX' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0, 500

Comment: thats exactly what i put in the database it retuned two rows

Comment: Of course that works. It follows the right `FROM JOIN WHERE` structure. Your question does not follow that structure :/ Look at the code in your question :)

Comment: my question goes from Join where

Comment: @user2354835 You have updated it, it is clear in the log that was not the case in the first place.

Comment: No, because you still have the PHP errors and also you haven't added the space as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: it works when i hard code the city and state In it does not with the variable $city or $state i know that the post is working i checked it